# using wget to download a directory

Tags: bash, wget

I'm trying to download all the files in an online directory. The command I'm using is:

`wget -r -np -nH -R index.html 
http://www.oecd-nea.org/dbforms/data/eva/evatapes/mendl_2/`

Using this command I get an empty directory. If I specify file names at the end I can get one at a time, but I'd like to get them all at once. Am I just missing something simple?

output from command:

--2015-03-14 14:54:05-- http://www.oecd-nea.org/dbforms/data/evaevatapes/mendl_2/
Resolving www.oecd-nea.org... 193.51.64.80
Connecting to www.oecd-nea.org|193.51.64.80|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: âdbforms/data/eva/evatapes/mendl_2/index.htmlâdbforms/data/eva/evatapes/mendl_2/index.htmlârobots.txtârobots.txt

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question to me.

Comment: I'd argue it is -- it's about programmatically downloading files

Comment: Is there a better forum to post this type of question too?

Comment: I gave it a try (bash, ubuntu 14.04) and it's working. Can you copy-paste the full result when you're asking it to your shell ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the depth of links you want to follow (`-l1`, since you only want to follow one link):

```
wget -e robots=off -l1 -r -np -nH -R index.html http://www.oecd-nea.org/dbforms/data/eva/evatapes/mendl_2/
```

I also added `-e robots=off`, since there is a `robots.txt` which would normally stop wget from going through that directory. For the rest of the world:

- `-r` recursive,
- `-np` no parent directory
- `-nH` no spanning across hosts

Comment: I gave it a try, empty directory again

Comment: @Marcus Müller You forgot index.html after -R

Comment: Ah! It seems that there's a robot.txt stopping you from downloading this. So I've added `-e robots=off `, @Arland .

Comment: Indeed, nice one. Maybe you should explain that directly in your answer.